# Python Scapy and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, scapy

I'm trying to create simple executable with pyinstaller from script I use for testing so I do not have to install everything on server I'm testing from.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

sourceport=int(raw_input('Soruce port:'))
destinationport=int(raw_input('Destination port:'))
destinationip=raw_input('Destination IP:')
maxttl=int(raw_input('MAX TTL:'))

for i in range(1,maxttl):
     udptrace = IP(dst=destinationip,ttl=i)/UDP(dport=destinationport,sport=sourceport,len=500)
     received=sr1(udptrace,verbose=0,timeout=2)
     try:
         print received.summary()
     except AttributeError:
         print "** TIMEOUT **"
```

Then I make executable:

`pyinstaller -F udp.py`

However when I run it and I have the following error:

```
Soruce port:500
Destination port:500
Destination IP:4.4.4.4
MAX TTL:3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
NameError: name 'IP' is not defined
user@:~/2/dist$
```

I have spent some time researching but did not find any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

First, we need to pinpoint the exact problem.

The *PyInstaller* manual [specifies](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs) that:

> Some Python scripts import modules in ways that *PyInstaller* cannot detect: for example, by using the `__import__()` function with variable data.

Inspecting [*Scapy*'s source code](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/src) reveals that this is exactly how the various networking layers are imported:

1. `scapy/layers/all.py`:

   ```
   def _import_star(m):
       mod = __import__(m, globals(), locals())
       for k,v in mod.__dict__.iteritems():
           globals()[k] = v

   for _l in conf.load_layers:
       log_loading.debug("Loading layer %s" % _l)
       try:
           _import_star(_l)
       except Exception,e:
       log.warning("can't import layer %s: %s" % (_l,e))
   ```

   Note that `__import__` is invoked for each module in `conf.load_layers`.
2. `scapy/config.py`:

   ```
   class Conf(ConfClass):
       """This object contains the configuration of scapy."""
        load_layers = ["l2", "inet", "dhcp", "dns", "dot11", "gprs", "hsrp", "inet6", "ir", "isakmp", "l2tp",
                      "mgcp", "mobileip", "netbios", "netflow", "ntp", "ppp", "radius", "rip", "rtp",
                      "sebek", "skinny", "smb", "snmp", "tftp", "x509", "bluetooth", "dhcp6", "llmnr", "sctp", "vrrp",
                      "ipsec" ]
   ```

   Note that `Conf.load_layers` contains `"inet"`.
3. The file `scapy/layers/inet.py` defines the `IP` class, which was not imported successfully in the enclosed example.

### The solution

Now, that we have located the root cause, let's see what can be done about it.

The *PyInstaller* manual [suggests](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs) some workarounds to such importing issues:

> - You can give additional files on the *PyInstaller* command line.
> - You can give additional import paths on the command line.
> - You can edit the `myscript.spec` file that *PyInstaller* writes the first time you run it for your script. In the spec file you can tell *PyInstaller* about code and data files that are unique to your script.
> - You can write "hook" files that inform *PyInstaller* of hidden imports. If you "hook" imports for a package that other users might also use, you can contribute your hook file to *PyInstaller*.

A bit of googling reveals that an appropriate "hook" was already added to the default *PyInstaller* distribution, in this [commit](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/7c9c9ab7b81eae3885e2152145b2993aa565675f), which introduced the file `PyInstaller/hooks/hook-scapy.layers.all.py`.

The *PyInstaller* manuals [indicates](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-hook-files) that such built-in hooks should run automatically:

> In summary, a "hook" file tells *PyInstaller* about hidden imports called by a particular module. The name of the hook file is `hook-<module>.py` where "`<module>`" is the name of a script or imported module that will be found by Analysis. You should browse through the existing hooks in the hooks folder of the *PyInstaller* distribution folder, if only to see the names of the many supported imports.
>
> For example `hook-cPickle.py` is a hook file telling about hidden imports used by the module `cPickle`. When your script has `import cPickle` the Analysis will note it and check for a hook file `hook-cPickle.py`.

### Bottom Line

Therefore, please verify that you're running the latest version of *PyInstaller*. If you can't upgrade to the latest version, or if it doesn't contain the file `PyInstaller/hooks/hook-scapy.layers.all.py`, then create it with the [following content](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-scapy.layers.all.py):

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2013, PyInstaller Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License with exception
# for distributing bootloader.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import collect_submodules

# The layers to load can be configured using scapy's conf.load_layers.
#  from scapy.config import conf; print(conf.load_layers)
# I decided not to use this, but to include all layer modules. The
# reason is: When building the package, load_layers may not include
# all the layer modules the program will use later.

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('scapy.layers')
```

Comment: Thank you Yoel for all effort and details you have put together ! , I had latest version of pyinstaller however I removed and installed it again just in case but file was not there, than I just copied hook from github and my little tool works ! this will save me a lot of effort. Thank you Again !

Comment: For pyinstaller 3 you must use the following code to import **collect_submodules** : 
`from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules`
[PyInstaller Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks)